# Task creation criteria in design phase of an embedded software

Tags: embedded, software-design, freertos

I would like to know if there is any objective criteria to decide how many task an embedded system should have.
For example if I have to implemented a protocol, with several layers, how how I decide if each layer should be a task or if I should implement everything in one task.
Is there any book that covers this type or architecture/design decision?

Thanks.

Comment: Too broad and too vague I think.  Tasks are about managing resources and scheduling CPU time to meet deadlines, not about functional partitioning implied perhaps by your protocol stack example.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is basically no, there are no objective criteria.

You can definitely have too many tasks.  Examples of thresholds for having too many tasks might be: (1) when there is more code than there would be with fewer tasks, (2) when it is more work to maintain the code than it would be with fewer tasks or (3) when you run out of memory for all your tasks!

How to know when you have too few tasks is harder to define because many sensible designs for simple projects use only a single task.  The threshold of maintainability applies, obviously.  If you find you are having to write lots of asynchronous APIs that would be a lot easier to use if they were blocking, then maybe you need more tasks.  If you find you are writing something generic that schedules the work to be done in a task, then maybe you need separate tasks.

Comment: I really appreciate you sharing your point of view about this topic.

Answer (score 1):

Simplified: everything that needs to execute simultaneously with other parts of the program and act independently of them is a candidate for a task. Hardware drivers often fulfil this criteria, so it makes perfect sense to for example have one task for a UART driver and another to encode/decode the packet contents. You'd implement some double-buffering mechanic and protect it with semaphores.

A professional project would do this:

- Write down the specification.
- Sketch up all modules/classes needed to meet the specification and their dependencies.
- Look at these modules/classes and see which ones that might be time-critical and/or handle hardware autonomously (again, typically all drivers).
- Decide if the project is complex enough to benefit from a RTOS or if you should do bare metal.
- Make an estimation of how much CPU, RAM and flash you'll need.
- Look for suitable MCUs, tool chains and other key components.

Comment: I really appreciate you sharing your point of view about this topic.